# downloading and storing files from given url to given path in lua

Tags: lua

I'm new with lua but working on an application that works on specific files with given path. Now, I want to work on files that I download. Is there any lua libraries or line of codes that I can use for downloading and storing it on my computer ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the LuaSocket library and its [`http.request`](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html#request) function to download using HTTP from an URL.

The function has two flavors:

- Simple call: `http.request('http://stackoverflow.com')`
- Advanced call: `http.request { url = 'http://stackoverflow.com', ... }`

The simple call returns 4 values - the entire content of the URL in a string, HTTP response code, headers and response line. You can then save the content to a file using the [`io`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.8) library.

The advanced call allows you to set several parameters like HTTP method and headers. An important parameter is `sink`. It represents a [LTN12-style sink](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FiltersSourcesAndSinks). For storing to file, you can use [`sink.file`](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/ltn12.html#sink.file):

```
local file = ltn12.sink.file(io.open('stackoverflow', 'w'))
http.request {
    url = 'http://stackoverflow.com',
    sink = file,
}
```

Comment: getting the following with the `local file` statement: `attempt to index local 'file' (a function value)`

Comment: @crockpotveggies please post full source code (somewhere like pastebin) that is failing you, together with the version of luasocket, since the short snippet in this answer works as intended.