# Lua - Parsing XML from a URL

Tags: xml, parsing, lua, steam-web-api

I want to parse this XML http://steamcommunity.com/id/GreenMarineValve?xml=1 with Lua 5.1, there are some libraries like LuaXML but they do not support parsing from the URL.

Would you give me a link to a library to do that if there is any or some advice to achieve my goal?

-

*More details for those who have experience with Steam's Web API*, I basically want to convert "customURL" to Steam Community ID (steamID64), but I see there is no other way doing it without parsing that XML file, I could parse it from the URL if it was JSON format instead of XML.

Is there an API I'm missing which will take the customURL as a parameter and return the communityID ?
Some related links to WebAPI:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API
https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/webapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to get the contents of a URL into a Lua string, then getting the fields you want is simple:

```
function get(data,name)
    return data:match("<"..name..">(.-)</"..name..">")
end

-- assumes C contains the downloaded contents
print(get(C,"customURL"))
print(get(C,"steamID64"))
```

Comment: This is indeed very useful code snippet for me, but I don't know how to get the contents of a URL.

Comment: @Fiat, try [LuaSocket](http://luaforge.net/projects/luasocket/) or [LuaCURL](http://luacurl.luaforge.net). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413127/downloading-and-storing-files-from-given-url-to-given-path-in-lua.

Comment: This is going to be way advanced for me, I feel so lost. But this answers my question anyways, I will try to understand it.

Comment: @Fiat, if you have `curl` or `wget` installed, you can open a pipe to them and read from it: `f=io.popen("curl -s http://steamcommunity.com/id/GreenMarineValve?xml=1"); C=f:read"*a"; f:close()`.

Comment: Thank you so much really, I will install curl and try this.