# Download file by url in lua

Tags: lua, luasocket

Lua beginner here. :)

I am trying to load a file by url and somehow I am just too stupid to get all the code samples here on SO to work for me.

[How to download a file in Lua, but write to a local file as it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479783/how-to-download-a-file-in-lua-but-write-to-a-local-file-as-it-works)

[downloading and storing files from given url to given path in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413127/downloading-and-storing-files-from-given-url-to-given-path-in-lua)

```
socket = require("socket")
http = require("socket.http")
ltn12 = require("ltn12")

local file = ltn12.sink.file(io.open('test.jpg', 'w'))
http.request {
    url = 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CCROQ8vUEAEgFke.jpg',
    sink = file,
}
```

my program runs for 20 - 30s and afterwards nothing is saved. There is a created test.jpg but it is empty.
I also tried to add w+b to the `io.open()` second parameter but did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following works:

```
-- retrieve the content of a URL
local http = require("socket.http")
local body, code = http.request("http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CCROQ8vUEAEgFke.jpg")
if not body then error(code) end

-- save the content to a file
local f = assert(io.open('test.jpg', 'wb')) -- open in "binary" mode
f:write(body)
f:close()
```

The script you have works for me as well; the file may be empty if the URL can't be accessed (the script I posted will return an error in this case).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I got a timeout. 
Test.lua:4: timeout
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'error'
 ...i\Downloads\ZeroBraneStudio\myprograms\Autonomy\Test.lua:4: in main chunk
 [C]: at 0x00402a57

Comment: This means some sort of connectivity issue, but not a problem with the Lua script. Try accessing the same URL from a browser on the same computer and you are likely to get the same error.

Comment: I tried to but there is no problem opening it in my browser (chrome).

Comment: I don't have a good explanation as the script works for me and the URL is valid. Maybe outgoing requests from your script are blocked by the firewall? Try to disable the firewall for outgoing calls or try running the script from a different computer.

Comment: Ok, I did that. There is no timeout anymore but whether I use your or my script the saved .jpg is only 55kb big but the image cannot be viewed. If I try to view it Windows displays an error saying that it seems like it is damaged or corrupted. Did you get a perfectly fine image which is viewable?

Comment: if you are on Windows use "wb" to save the file as binary as you probably end up with broken file because of end-of-line conversion. I updated the example.

Comment: I tried the update the above so it works with an image hosted on a https site, ````local https = require "ssl.https" --luasec
local body, code = https.request("https://u.cubeupload.com/jbcooper/16146313918060.jpg")
print(code)
if not body then error(code) end
local f = assert(io.open('mnt/nas/webtest2.jpg', 'wb')) -- open in "binary" mode
f:write(body)
f:close() ```` but it didnt work, no code, nothing. what have I missed ?

Comment: You should get an error message as the second returned value if the first one is `nil`.

Comment: Nope, thats what i thought but i get nothing.. very strange.