# How do you read json file from a website in lua scripting?

Tags: bash, lua

Basically I've been using this code to read json file from web API and it's pretty easy using bash with jq package.

```
 #!/bin.bash
 ip_country=$(curl -s "https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/123.123.123.123}" | jq --raw-output '.name')
 if [ -z "$ip_country" ]; then
      ip_country="Unknown"
 fi
 echo "${ip_country}"
```

But, in lua, I have done some research and seems like [`lunajson`](https://github.com/grafi-tt/lunajson) is the best package to handle a json file (IMO). I know how to read a simple json file using `lunajson` but I found no example how to use this to read json file from a website like the bash example. Is there a special package that I need to import in order to read the json file from website (like the bash example above)?

Comment: `print(io.popen"wget -qO- https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/123.123.123.123":read():match'"name":"(.-)"')`

Comment: Wow so basically I can use all the linux commands to execute in lua using popen?. Sorry I'm pretty new to LUA.

Comment: Please write answer that you have just written, I will accept it.

Comment: @KalibZen You can simply use `socket.http` Lua package to download your file.

Comment: @stephanmg do i need to install another package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file by url in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654194/download-file-by-url-in-lua)

Comment: @KalibZen Try to see if `socket.http` is available to you by `require("socket.http")`  in Lua.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223438/discussion-between-stephanmg-and-kalib-zen).

Comment: I used the given method from @Egor Skriptunoff. It's working right now, but I just need somebody to write an answer for this so that this question would have an answer.

Comment: @KalibZen could you use the chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can install additional Lua packages (e.g. via Luarocks), then you can use the following pure-Lua solution (Tested with Lua 5.1.5 on Ubuntu):

```
-- read remote file from website
http = require("socket.http")
local body, code = socket.http.request("http://website/with/json/file.json")
if not body then error(code) end
local file = assert(io.open('file.json', 'w'))
file:write(body)
file:close()

-- read local file 
local open = io.open
local file = open("file.json", "rb")
if not file then return nil end
local jsonString = file:read "*a"
file:close()

-- parse json with lunajson
local json = require 'lunajson'
local t = lunajson.decode(jsonString)
print(t)
```

Note that you need to install `socket.http` and `lunajson` with:

```
luarocks install luasocket --local
luarocks install lunajson --local
```

And eventually you want to adjust your `LUA_PATH` by means of using `luarocks path --bin` respectively with `eval $(luarocks path --bin)` the LUA_PATH will be exported automatically.