# How to downloading .exe files using Lua Scripts?

Tags: lua, download

i never worked with Lua and want to know if it's possible to download an .exe File and saving to Disk.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'd better start looking at their documentation first.

Comment: I don't want to read entire documentation just for a download

Comment: Yes, its possible, but with some extenal libraries or tools

Answer (score 0):

Lua do not support download itself, it must rely on extenal liabraries like luasocket. you can refer the answer [download file by url in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654194/download-file-by-url-in-lua)